# Unity : DictationRecognizer needs internet connection?

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-recognition

we use DictationRecognizer in Unity and once the network was unvailable, the DictationRecognizer fails.
The KeywordRecognizer doesn't need internet connection but DictationRecognizer does ?
We need to use it on devices without internet connection and we need data protection because it is for medical domain.
How is managed the privacy of the audio data send to the cloud ?
Somebody has a local solution for DictationRecognizer in Unity or has information about data privacy concerning the audio files send to external servers ?
Thanks in advance
Best

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. It is free and works on windows 10 only.

For dictation it requires internet connection.
For keyword recognition it works only with provided phrases.